# SSL Certificate Management and Expiration Notification

Tags: tls

What utilities are good for notifying admins of SSL certificates that are about to expire?

Symantec and DigiCert have certificate management products, but what systems or utilities do you use to keep track of expiring certificates?

Answer (score 0):

They are lot of utilities available to notify the expiry date of the SSL certificate and most of them depends upon the application specific. For simplicity, you can write your own script or code and you can customize the things more simpler. even  you can do with openssl or keytool to run in a cron job to send a mail or sms automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Could literally just use the calendar on your phone or computer, and/or [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) if you want to schedule programmatically. Could also use something like [Gmail Delay Send](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/) to e-mail yourself in the future if you are worried that DigiCert or Symantec will forget to hit you up for money around that time.

Answer (score 0):

If running on linux, certmonger does exactly that: it keeps track of certificates, and if you have libraries setup for it, warns you when these are close to expiry and if librsries for this are available and configured, also takes action automatically (like submitting a certificate for renewal, receiving the new one, installing it where needed and even refreshing daemons afterwards).

This is, of course, all dependent on having the correct plugins in place for such actions, or writing your own in python if they don't exist yet. From my experience, for instance, it integrates very well with Fedora's IPA (RedHat's IdM) solution, part of which is a CA.